# Setting Json values in Powershell found using pipecommands

Tags: json, powershell

I have a JSON file that I am reading into a PowerShell object. I want to be able to replace certain values which I find using the where command and pipes.

```
[
   {
      "name":"name-1",
      "targets":[
         {
            "attribute":"Country",
            "opt":"In",
            "values":[
               "@country"
            ]
         },
         {
            "attribute":"Environment",
            "opt":"In",
            "values":[
               "@Environment"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "value":{
         "Url":"@url",
         "Version":"@version"
      }
   }
]
```

I specifically want to replace the what `@url`, `@version`, `@country` and `@environment` with the values I specify in the powershell.

Setting the `value.Url` and `value.Version` seems to work with:

```
$body=Get-Content -Raw -Path "$path\$filename.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
$body.value.Url=$applicationUrl;
$body.Value.Version = $applicationVersion;
```

But the targets attribute is a list, so I have to find using the where statement and pipes. Although I can find the correct element using:

```
$body.Targets | where { $_.attribute -eq "environment" } | Select -First 1 | Select-Object -Property values
```

All my attempts to set the value have failed, it always remains as is.  Powershell is interpreting the object like:

```
$body.Targets | where { $_.attribute -eq "environment" } | Select -First 1 | Select-Object -Property values


TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                     
----        ----------   ----------                     
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj) 
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()              
GetType     Method       type GetType()                 
ToString    Method       string ToString()              
values      NoteProperty Object[] values=System.Object[]
```

How could I set the values property on this object?  I just want it to be a string like "qa" or "production"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the value attribute as follows:

```
($body.Targets | Where-Object { $_.attribute -eq "environment" } | Select-Object -First 1).values = @("VALUE");
```

Comment: Wouldn't this change the `values` array to a String?

Comment: Thanks ,that pointed me in the right direction ($body.Targets | where { $_.attribute -eq "environment" } | Select -First 1).values = @("qa")